# I need to get a line that contains a certain word from the output of a batch file and save it as a string in C#. How would I do this?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch file that searches my computer for a folder with a specific name. This batch file executes when I start my C#/wpf application and finds the absolute file path of the folder I need. I need to save that file path as a string but I have not been able to successfully accomplish this so far. How would I do this?

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var pSpawn = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
        {

        FileName = "C:/Desktop/MasterIndex/Notflix/WpfPresentationLayer/test.bat",
        Arguments ="/c dir /b",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
        }
        };

        pSpawn.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        pSpawn.Start();
        pSpawn.BeginOutputReadLine();
        pSpawn.WaitForExit();

        string BatchOutput = sb.ToString();

        string AbsolutePath;

        if (BatchOutput.Contains(@"MasterIndex")) 
        {
            BatchOutput.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  
                .Select(line => line)
                              .ToArray().ToString();


        }
```

Batch file

```
   cd \
   dir *MasterIndex*.* /s
```

Comment: Use the `FOR` command with the `/D` and `/R` options. `FOR /D /R %%G IN (*MasterIndex*) DO set var=%%G`

Comment: How would I set that variable as a string then?

Comment: Thank you, that pretty much solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code I whipped up a few months back to solve a similar problem.  I find that encapsulating what I learn into a class like this, is more convenient than relearning it the next time I run across a similar problem, but this is very simple/crude/incomplete.  I have used a few times, example usage below.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// WIP: This class is incomplete in design and implementation.

/// <summary>
/// Wrapper class for running separate processes, and capturing/
/// redirecting their I/O.
/// </summary>
public class ShellExec
{
    #region public

    /// <summary>
    /// The args to run Cmd with.
    /// </summary>
    public string Args { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The command to execute.
    /// </summary>
    public string Cmd { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ProcessStartInfo used to execute the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Initialized by the constructors. Can be modified before calling
    /// RunSync() or RunAsync().
    /// </remarks>
    public ProcessStartInfo ProcessStartInfo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Process object used to execute the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Initialized by the constructors. Can be modified before calling
    /// RunSync() or RunAsync().
    /// </remarks>
    public Process Process { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The captured output from the last command execution.
    /// </summary>
    public string Result
    {
        get => _result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run Cmd with Args, synchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int RunSync()
    {
        Process.Start();
        _result = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        return Process.ExitCode;
    }

#if false
    /// <summary>
    /// Run Cmd with Args, asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void RunAsync()
    {
        return 0;
    }
#endif
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple constructor, uses our default ProcessStartInfo settings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmd"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public ShellExec(string cmd, string args)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(Cmd, Args)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,  // Capture output.
            UseShellExecute = false,        // No graphical shell.
            CreateNoWindow = true           // Execute in background (no window).
        };

        Initialize(cmd, args, psi);
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #endregion public

    #region private

    private string _result;

    private void Initialize(string cmd, string args, ProcessStartInfo psi)
    {
        psi.FileName = Cmd = cmd;
        psi.Arguments = Args = args;
        ProcessStartInfo = psi;
        Process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = ProcessStartInfo
        };
    }
    // Hide default constructor.
    private ShellExec() {}

    #endregion private
}
```

Usage:

```
ShellExec se = new ShellExec("cmd.exe", "/c dir");
int exitCode = se.RunSync();

Console.WriteLine(se.Result);
```